# How to remove some rows in table via EntityManager?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, entitymanager

For example in sql query it will:

```
delete from Mails where name='....'
```

How to execute this via EntityManager?

Comment: entityManager.remove(name)

Comment: its not working. I'm tried:
EntityManager em = Server.emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
Mails mail = new Mails();
mail.setName(username);
em.remove(mail);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a named query.  [Here's an example](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named):

```
query = em.createNamedQuery("SELECT c FROM Country c");
List results = query.getResultList();
```

Instead of using a select, use a delete the way you want.  Note that this doesn't use SQL, but [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html).

Comment: em.createQuery().executeQuery solved my problem. Thank you.